# Find substring within a string using Linq and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq, lambda

I have a string such as following:

**This is [[Data:Example]] of some [[Data:Next]] string.**

What I need to get, is the following words:

- Example
- Next

I can do it by finding first occurence of **[[Data** and continue looping until I find **]]**; however I know this can be done also with LINQ + REGEX expression.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why would you use linq for string manipulation?

Comment: what did you try? gives us some of your codes.

Comment: This would actually be a good case for regular expressions. I don't know why you think LINQ would help you with it.

Comment: Does not have to be necessarily LINQ, but LINQ offers simplified foreach loops...that's why it came to my mind

Comment: completely forgot about regular expressions!

Comment: Using linq on strings will treat the string as an array or char.  Probably not what you want.  As @Dirk says, regex is the way to go.  Now you have two problems ;)

Comment: This is exactly what Regex was designed for...

Comment: Linq does simplify looping in some sort, but your conditions are still the same. Show your code using loops and show your attempts to translate that to Linq.

Comment: Try string operations: IndexOf, StartsWith, EndsWith, Contains, or LastIndexOf.  There are also regular expressions as suggested by Dirk.

Comment: [C# List Examples - Basics](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) I would suggest doing some googling and show a bit more effort.. what you are wanting is not that difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[\[Data:(.*?)\]\]");
Group[] groups = rx.Matches("This is [[Data:Example]] of some [[Data:Next]] string.")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1])
    .ToArray();

foreach (Group gr in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(gr.ToString());
}
```

This will use Regex + Linq to find the various "words".

As written by dasblinkenlight, there is another way to do the regex:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[\[Data:((?:(?!\]\]).)*)\]\]");
```

This regex "stops" when it finds two `]]` (by using a negative lookhead), while the first one uses a lazy quantifier to do the same. You'll have to benchmark them to find the fastest (but it's important only for big blocks of text)

Comment: Plus one this because regex and linq :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No, it won't. It will break if there are two "consecutive" ]], not one. It will match **next[i]=j**

Comment: @xanatos Oops, I see you've got a reluctant qualifier in there. It may cause a lot of backtracking, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Contains()` method.

```
string longer = "this id my longer string";
string find = "longer";
if(longer.Contains(find))
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to get a list of those words, not to check if they exist

Comment: @RobertJ. if you need a list of those words.. then look up how the `Add Method` works for List<T> also do some more research on your end.. and edit your question to fit express what you need otherwise what answer is posted here would be correct.. Update your original question I am voting to close this because you have not been clear enough

Answer (score 0):

`.*\[\[Data\.(.*)\]\].*[\[Data\.(.*)\]\]` should give you two groups `$1` and `$2`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression to match on:

```
\[\[Data\:(?<data>([^\]]+))\]\]
```

The capture `data` will contain all information between the data tags. Note that this will search for the first `]` to find the end of the tag. It will not work if `]` is a valid character *inside* the data tags.